# Linking CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, audio

[image]

So my CSS doesn't work for some reason. I have searched online and cannot find a problem with it but the CSS is not connecting to the HTML. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yee.css">.
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id="yee" src="C:\Users\Jake Coffey\Downloads\yee.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        <center><img src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/smashbroslawlorigins/images/1/16/Yee.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/280?cb=20140904202925" onclick="document.getElementById('yee').play();" /></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? If your html file is in the root directory... does .../css/yee.css exist? Also are you sure your styles are actually not being applied? Try body { background-color: green }

Comment: Try to close link tag and remove dot in the end.
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/yee.css" />

Answer (score 6):

This maybe... never mind...
But I got this problem.

Try add `/` to your link tag end

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yee.css"/>
```

Comment: and this dot after <link> looks doubtfully

Comment: Thanks for help, I got it working somehow. The css code was incorrect so i had to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because we can't see your file structure. 
This href you are using `href="css/yee.css"` is assuming that your files look like this.

```
/ project-folder
  index.html
  / css
    yee.css
```

The href tells your HTML file where to look for the CSS file. If your CSS file is in the same folder as your HTML file try changing the href to `href="yee.css"`

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

https://codepen.io/718studio/project/editor/ABPvrZ/

Comment: I have changed code and files around. CSS still not working. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you type the href correctly :

href="yourfolder/yourcssstylename.css"

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the link the same level as `index.html` directed to the css folder.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfolder/css/styles.css">
```

or only `...href="css/styles.css">` and make sure delete `/` before css file name.

Answer (score 0):

its always better to specify full address for css file like

```
 href="http://localhost/public/css/yee.css"
```

and make sure you use correct protocol http:// or https for your server.

ps you can save your site directory as a constant, in order to not check links during deployment