# How to fix a css linking issue

Tags: html, css

I want to make a simple style for me so I linked one CSS file and when I open my HTML file in the browser the style is not applied and when I op the console it gives me error.

I have tried `!DOCTYPE html, type="text/css"` but nothing worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css">
```

The result is only the HTML file without anything from the CSS and the console 
error that show is:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/styles.css' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,
>   and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: refer this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379971/linking-css-doesnt-work

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: make sure the path you given in href is true or not.? the link you dine the way is correct but the file structure matter here to load css file.

Comment: Show us your folder structure if you need further help

Comment: also i am using express server node js

Comment: the css file is in the same folder as the html file

Comment: did you write your style in <style> tag in your HTML file? and is it worked ?? and check your attach link and make sure it shows you your CSS codes

Comment: in the style tag the code worked

Answer (score 1):

Can you browse your URL `http://127.0.0.1:3001/styles.css`. Make sure your path is accurate. If it does try them out

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="./styles.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css" />
```

or  just move your CSS files into "assets/" directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles.css" >
```

Answer (score 1):

to check whether stylesheet works or not, the easiest way is to keep your CSS file in the same directory where your index.html file is located and then try:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCssFileName.css">